# Is it possible to maintain Application Scope in Spring Webflow?

Tags: scope, spring-webflow

I have a significant logic which applies to all the users using the application. Using conversion scope I was able to maintain the data but when it comes to performance, each time user loads the logic taking almost 50% of CPU Usage. So, I am thinking to load the logic on application startup and keep the data on application scope so that all users Conversations have access to it ?

Any suggestions or ideas or referrals are highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Webflow can access all of your spring beans. If you have Spring manage bean that can return the data, then you can access it from your flow definition. Webflow uses the bean name when resolving the bean.

In the below snippet, we call the Spring managed bean `multiFactorManager` and store the result in a flow scoped variable.

```
<on-entry>
        <evaluate
            expression="multiFactorManager.getMultiFactorSettings(account)"
            result="flowScope.multiFactorSettings" />
</on-entry>
```